# MATLAB solve array

Tags: arrays, matlab, solver

I've got multiple arrays that you can't quite fit a curve/equation to, but i do need to solve them for a lot of values. Simplified it looks like this when i plot it, but the real ones have a lot more points: [image: plot]
So say i would like to solve for y=22,how would i do that? As you can see there'd be three solutions to this, but i only need the most left one.
Linear is okay, but i'd rather us a non-linear method.

The only way i found is to fit an equation to a set of points and solve that equation, but an equation can't approximate the array accurately enough.

Comment: Can you give a sample of what your data looks like? (Numeric format, not a graph).

Comment: If you wan tto be very accurate you can always fit multiple equations peicewise-ly (?) and solve for each one

Comment: I could use simulink and then capture x when y is near 22, but how would i do that systematically with 25 arrays that need to be solved for 12 y values each?

Comment: If you cannot fit a curve to your points and linear is okay, then just iterate all points x_i and look for `x(i)>=22 && x(i+1)<=22` and then calculate the linear intersection in between i and i+1.

Comment: @StewieGriffin My data, ie the arrays, look like this:  [558.54 706.1 909.76 1039.29 1106.82 1115.11 1168.37 1199.76 1160.57 1189.41 1204.17] plotted along [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.7 0.8 0.9 0.965 1] while i need to find eg. 1175.

Comment: Consider using [spline](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spline.html) method.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation uses a first-order interpolation- if you're looking for higher accuracy and it feels appropriate, you can use a similar strategy for another order estimator.

Assuming `data` is the name of your array containing data with `x` values in the first column and `y` values in the second, that the columns are sorted by increasing or decreasing x values, and you wanted to find all data at the value y = 22;

```
searchPoint = 22; %search for all solutions where y = 22
matchPoints = []; %matrix containing all values of x
for ii = 1:length(data)-1
    if (data(ii,2)>searchPoint)&&(data(ii+1,2)<searchPoint)
        xMatch = data(ii,1)+(searchPoint-data(ii,2))*(data(ii+1,1)-data(ii,1))/(data(ii+1,2)-data(ii,2)); %Linear interpolation to solve for xMatch
        matchPoints = [matchPoints xMatch];
    elseif (data(ii,2)<searchPoint)&&(data(ii+1,2)>searchPoint)
        xMatch = data(ii,1)+(searchPoint-data(ii,2))*(data(ii+1,1)-data(ii,1))/(data(ii+1,2)-data(ii,2)); %Linear interpolation to solve for xMatch
        matchPoints = [matchPoints xMatch];
    elseif (data(ii,2)==searchPoint) %check if data(ii,2) is equal
        matchPoints = [matchPoints data(ii,1)];
    end
end

if(data(end,2)==searchPoint) %Since ii only goes to the rest of the data
    matchPoints = [matchPoints data(end,1)];
end
```

This was written sans-compiler, but the logic was tested in octave (in other words, sorry if there's a slight typo in variable names, but the math should be correct)